# How to get whole month dates from a calendar instance and use it for any purpose?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-date

Can anyone tell me how to get whole month dates from calendar instance in Android. I need these dates to do some operation in my app. Kindly suggest an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want. As I know, we can use DatePicker api to get whole dates of months.
Codes like these:

```
    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.YOUR_LANGUAGE);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);      
    // initial datePicker
    datePicker.init(year, month, day, this);
```